# Can't get through 500 Internal Server Error in Nextcloud

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, mariadb, nextcloud

I’m getting an error when trying to access newly installed NextCloud. I would appreciate some help.

Page displays the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
More details can be found in the server log.
```

Config.php:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'XX',
  'passwordsalt' => 'XX',
  'secret' => 'XX',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'example.com',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/ncdata',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '19.0.3.1',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://example.com/',
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => 'var/www/html',
  'installed' => true,
  'maintenance' => false,
  'app_install_overwrite' => 
  array (
    0 => 'recommendation_assistant',
    1 => 'caniupdate',
    2 => 'admin_notifications',
    3 => 'end_to_end_encryption',
  ),
  'filelocking.enabled' => true,
  'memcache.locking' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'redis' => 
  array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => 6379,
    'timeout' => 0.0,
    'password' => '',
  ),
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'dbuser' => 'XX',
  'dbpassword' => 'XX',
  'updater.secret' => 'XXX',
  'theme' => '',
  'loglevel' => 2,
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'updater.release.channel' => 'stable',
  'twofactor_enforced' => 'false',
  'twofactor_enforced_groups' => 
  array (
  ),
  'twofactor_enforced_excluded_groups' => 
  array (
    0 => 'admin',
  ),
);
```

.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
     <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
        RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
     </IfModule>
     <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
     </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
 
   <IfModule mod_env.c>
     # Add security and privacy related headers
 
     # Avoid doubled headers by unsetting headers in "onsuccess" table,
     # then add headers to "always" table: https://github.com/nextcloud/server/pull/19002
     Header onsuccess unset Referrer-Policy
     Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-Content-Type-Options
     Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-Download-Options
     Header always set X-Download-Options "noopen"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-Frame-Options
     Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies
     Header always set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-Robots-Tag
     Header always set X-Robots-Tag "none"
 
     Header onsuccess unset X-XSS-Protection
     Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
 
     SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
   </IfModule>
 
   # Add cache control for static resources
   <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|svg|gif)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15778463"
   </FilesMatch>
 
   # Let browsers cache WOFF files for a week
   <FilesMatch "\.woff2?$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
   </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_php7.c>
   php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
   php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
   php_value output_buffering 0
   <IfModule mod_env.c>
     SetEnv htaccessWorking true
   </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DavClnt
   RewriteRule ^$ /remote.php/webdav/ [L,R=302]
   RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/nodeinfo /public.php?service=nodeinfo [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/(acme-challenge|pki-validation)/.*
   RewriteRule ^(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
   AddEncoding gzip svgz
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_dir.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
 </IfModule>
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8
 Options -Indexes
 <IfModule pagespeed_module>
   ModPagespeed Off
 </IfModule>
```

error.log

```
[Sat Nov 14 00:02:13.925600 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 444367] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 14 00:02:13.925696 2020] [core:notice] [pid 444367] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Nov 14 06:12:16.974834 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 1727847] [client 80.82.68.28:50912] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/config/getuser
```

I already tried to:

- Purge and reinstall php and all modules
- Changed permissions of all files to 640, directories to 750

**System details:**
Database: MariaDB
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
PHP: v7.4

Comment: Its an Apache error, its configuration needs changing. Your question doesn't include enough of the configuration or file paths to resolve this.

Comment: What else do I need to share?